# Query logic to get expected results based on group Exclusion list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Please find a below a trivial example with expected results for reference.

**DB: Oracle Database 12c**

**Sample query:**

```
with x as
(select 'John' farmer, 'FRUITGROUPA,FRUITGROUPB,ALLFRUIT,VEGGROUPA,VEGGROUPB,VEGGROUPC' grouper from dual),
y as
(select x.farmer,regexp_substr (x.grouper, '[^,]+', 1, level)  grouper
from x
connect by level <= regexp_count(x.grouper,',')+1),
z as
(select 'FRUITGROUPA' grouper,'FRUITS' classer, 'APPLE' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'FRUITGROUPB' grouper,'FRUITS' classer, 'APPLE,BANANA,WATERMELON' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'ALLFRUIT' grouper,'FRUITS' classer, '' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'VEGGROUPA' grouper,'VEG' classer, 'POTATO' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'VEGGROUPB' grouper,'VEG' classer, 'CARROT,LADYFINGER,POTATO' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'VEGGROUPC' grouper,'VEG' classer, 'POTATO,CARROT' exclusion from dual )
select * from y,z where y.grouper = z.grouper
```

**Corresponding data if we run the query:**

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+
| FARMER |   GROUPER   |  GROUPER_1  | CLASSER |        EXCLUSION         |
+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+
| John   | FRUITGROUPA | FRUITGROUPA | FRUITS  | APPLE                    |
| John   | FRUITGROUPB | FRUITGROUPB | FRUITS  | APPLE,BANANA,WATERMELON  |
| John   | ALLFRUIT    | ALLFRUIT    | FRUITS  |                          |
| John   | VEGGROUPA   | VEGGROUPA   | VEG     | POTATO                   |
| John   | VEGGROUPB   | VEGGROUPB   | VEG     | CARROT,LADYFINGER,POTATO |
| John   | VEGGROUPC   | VEGGROUPC   | VEG     | POTATO,CARROT            |
+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

**Expected output from final query:**

```
+---------+-----------+
| CLASSER | EXCLUSION |
+---------+-----------+
| FRUITS  |           |
| VEG     | POTATO    |
+---------+-----------+
```

**Logic:**

In the first class (fruits) the farmer is excluded from farming apple in FRUITGROUPA & FRUITGROUPB but not in ALLFRUIT group. Hence when it comes to overall restrictions the farmer is allowed to farm APPLE along with all other fruits,

In the second class (veg) the farmer is excluded from farming potato in all of its groups which correspond to class (veg). Hence overall its excluded from farming potato but is allowed to farm all other vegetables.

I have failed to figure out a query to give such output in this whole scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
with groupsOneLine as(
  select 'John' farmer, 
         'FRUITGROUPA,FRUITGROUPB,ALLFRUIT,VEGGROUPA,VEGGROUPB,VEGGROUPC' grouper 
    from dual
),
groups_ as (
  select x.farmer,
         regexp_substr (x.grouper, '[^,]+', 1, level)  grouper
    from groupsOneLine x
 connect by level <= regexp_count(x.grouper,',')+1
),
exclusionsOneLine as (
 select 'FRUITGROUPA' grouper,'FRUITS' classer, 'APPLE' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'FRUITGROUPB' grouper,'FRUITS' classer, 'APPLE,BANANA,WATERMELON' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'ALLFRUIT' grouper,'FRUITS' classer, '' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'VEGGROUPA' grouper,'VEG' classer, 'POTATO' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'VEGGROUPB' grouper,'VEG' classer, 'CARROT,LADYFINGER,POTATO' exclusion from dual union all
 select 'VEGGROUPC' grouper,'VEG' classer, 'POTATO,CARROT' exclusion from dual 
),
exclusions_ as (
  select distinct 
         x.grouper,
         x.classer,
         regexp_substr (x.exclusion, '[^,]+', 1, level)  exclusion
    from exclusionsOneLine x
 connect by level <= regexp_count(x.exclusion,',')+1
),
exclusionsPerClasser as (
  select count(1) count_,
         x.classer,
         x.exclusion
    from exclusions_ x
   group by x.classer,
            x.exclusion
),
groupsPerClasser as (
  select count(1) count_,
         x.classer
    from exclusionsOneLine x
   group by x.classer
),
excludeInAllGroups  as (
  select e.classer,
         e.exclusion
    from groupsPerClasser g,
         exclusionsPerClasser e
   where g.classer = e.classer
     and g.count_ = e.count_
)
select g.classer,
       e.exclusion
  from groupsPerClasser g,
       excludeInAllGroups e
 where g.classer = e.classer (+)
;
```